# What is the causation of the mass deficit in atomic nuclei?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics, mass-energy, binding-energy

I've always heard that when protons and neutrons are combined together into nuclei, the mass of the product is less than the mass of the constituents. And that this mass is called the mass deficit and attributed to the loss in potential energy and sometimes (depending on source) considered equivalent to the binding energy of the product nuclei. The image below shows the change in potential energy of two protons approaching together, where the potential energy is derived from the resultant force of the strong force and electrostatic force. The minimum and maximum points on the graph show the resultant force = 0, derived from $$dU = -F(x)dx => -dU/dx = F(x).$$

Can anyone tell me which region of potential energy is lost as mass?
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by ‘which region’? There is a minimum in the interaction. Attributing to one part or another of the combined potential is fruitless.

Comment: You're not making sense to me here. What is the potential energy lost here when two protons combine?

Comment: Im assuming that at the second dU/dx = 0 point, that amount of potential energy gained is caused by the KE energy given to two protons. As they get closer, the strong force performs work on the protons and results in a decrease in the potential energy. As they get even closer, both the strong and electrostatic force become repulsive and the potential energy begins to increase again. So in this event, there are both increases a and decreases in potential energy. Im asking, which potential energy is considered to be lost as mass here? And how to identify it from the graph?

Comment: So you're saying the potential energy lost is the difference between the two stationary points on the graph? Which is the difference between the potential energy at which the strong force is able to overcome the electrostatic force to become attractive and the potential energy point where the protons are in stable equilibrium?

Comment: You can’t ascribe change in energy to one or the other. You can’t identify which from the graph. There is no point in trying to do so.

Comment: Im not looking for blind propositions here. If you are making propositions, please provide reasoned support for them. Its said that "potential energy is lost as mass when two protons combine", what exactly does this mean?

Comment: The second point where the curve has an unstable local maximum is irrelevant. The binding energy is by definition the difference between the value at V at the stable minimum and the value of V at infinite separation. There is a mass deficit because this binding energy is negative.

Comment: I think your problem is the curve itself , which treats nuclei as classical particles whereas their interactions are in the quantum mechanical regime where potentials enter in the equations that model the interaction, not between particles,. Do you have a link for the plot?

Comment: https://www.expii.com/t/strong-nuclear-force-vs-electrostatic-force-overview-8755

Comment: Can you explain why the unstable local maximum is irrelevant? Clearly, in theory to split a proton from another proton would require workdone by a theoretical force against the resultant force dominated by the attractive strong force from the equilibrium point towards the point where the resultant force becomes repulsive due to electrostatic force domination(shown by the second local maximum). At this point, there is no workdone by an external force to separate the protons further, since this separation is carried by the electrostatic force.

Comment: So what im proposing is that the binding energy is the difference between the two stationary points.

Comment: My reasoning is that, even if you performed the work done on the proton equal to your current definition. (Difference in V between local minimum to infinity), assuming potential energy is 0 at infinity. You can clearly see form the graph, performing this workdone on the proton, the proton would still be in the attractive region of the resultant force. Just look at where the graph intersects the x-axis.

Comment: The binding energy is simply the difference between the energy when the system is stably *bound* and the energy when the system is completely *unbound*. It’s a **definition**. I think the energy you’re talking about might be called the activation energy.

Comment: Two comments:  1) The strong nuclear force is highly spin dependent and you haven't said anything about the spins of your two protons, 2) Protons are quantum particles and you seem to be only addressing the issue from a classical potential point of view.

Comment: How do you address the issue from a quantum mechanical view point?